# Revamping old DOS games for a modern system

Tags: windows, gaming, ms-dos

I have a bunch of old DOS based games I would like to run on modern windows without an emulator like DOSbox and as a stand alone program. I noticed that back then piracy wasn't as big of a problem as it is today so I have access to all the files I need from the original disks.

I was wondering if I can use the old files and rewrite some code (or the whole game) to create a version for modern windows to process. Other motivations for this is that some of the old DOS games I have won't work with DOSbox for whatever reason.

I want to know whether this is possible and also a point in the right direction to the skills needed to do this. I have a good grasp of several programming languages (c++, javascript, assembly, and web languages) and think I can do this but I don't know how to hack these games inside out and revamp them. I plan to start with [*Blake Stone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blake_Stone:_Aliens_of_Gold), which is one of my favorites.

Comment: I don't mean this in a bad way, but if you have to ask what skills are needed to do this, that's a pretty good indication that your learning curve would be such that this isn't something you would be prepared to tackle any time soon.  Something to think about.  Just sayin'.

Comment: no it's not possible. 64-bit Windows can't run 16-bit applications so the only way is to use an emulator

Comment: @phuclv You may want to re-read the question

Comment: @gronostaj yes I already read the question before commenting and it's still impossible. "Rewrite some code" implies the OP has some code which is almost zero chance, and rewrite only part of the binary will not change the fact that it's still 16-bit and won't be executable

Comment: @phuclv OP wants to reverse-engineer the game (but they don't know that term) and rebuild it for x64. Whether this is practical or not is already addressed in the answers. But this question is not about running 16-bit code natively on 64-bit OSes. They already know that - otherwise they would ask how to run them, not how to "rewrite some code".

Answer (score 2):

> I noticed that back then piracy wasn't as big of a problem as it is today so I have access to all the files I need from the original disks.

I don't know where you got that idea.  Having unique-per-game "Copy protection" methods seemed to be more common back in the DOS era than today.

> I was wondering if I can use the old files and rewrite some code (or the whole game) to create a version for modern windows to process.

Sure.  There is nothing technically preventing you from re-writing the whole game.  Note that I'm just referring to what is possible, from a technology standpoint.  Many popular games were "intellectual property", so there may be some issues from a standpoint of legality.

> I want [...] the right direction to the skills needed to do this.

The first thing to do, before investing a bunch of time in a programming project, is to see what is already done.  Don't uselessly repeat a bunch of work (and possibly do an inferior job), only to later learn that there is a popular re-release that already accomplished your goals.  Many organizations have released source code of some popular software, including "id Software".  (A comment by Giacomo1968, mentioned earlier on this page, refers to the "open" source code for "Wolfenstein 3D Engine".  The Blake Stone game simply used a minor enhancement to that engine, so check on that engine.)  Other popular re-releases/re-makes include Descent ][ ([Descent 2 @ DDN](http://www.descent2.com/ddn/sources/descent2/) ; and [D2X project](https://icculus.org/d2x/) and hyperlinked projects).  For WarCraft ][, there is [War2.ru](http://War2.ru) unofficial port/remake.  Clones may include [Stratagus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratagus) (WarCraft 2), or [FreeDOOM](https://freedoom.github.io).  Those are just some selections based on some games I've enjoyed (which were popular around the time of Blake Stone, or shortly after).  Many others exist, as seen by [Wikipedia's list of commercial video games with available source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_commercial_video_games_with_available_source_code), and [Wikipedia's list of Open Source video games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open-source_video_games).

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if I can use the old files and rewrite some code (or the whole game) to create a version for modern windows to process

It is, but will require a lot of work as DOS programs expect direct access to the hardware so you have to convert all that to OS calls, and also expect total control of the hardware and interrupts so timing may be very hard to get right.  A few very old DOS games expect the CPU clock speed to be a specific speed and exact timing to work properly, which the OS interferes with (e.g. IIRC Digger expects a 4.77Mhz CPU and no faster) so even this may not get the original code to run without so many changes that you basically kill the essence of the game.

> I want to know whether this is possible and also a point in the right direction to the skills needed to do this. I have a good grasp of several programming languages (c++, javascript, assembly, and web languages) and think I can do this but I don't know how to hack these games inside out and revamp them.

Reverse engineering is the skill you need.  You don't really want to do raw OS calls from assembly, and especially not anything involving graphics I/O (you'll be basically re-implementing C at that point) so you are further looking into basically converting the assembly to C or other high level language.